# Separate cpuset for jobs

Tags: pbs, torque, cgroups, cpuset

Is there a way to restrict cpus and memory for users running scripts directly, but allow more cpus and memory on job submission?

I am running torque/pbs on Ubuntu 14.04 server and want to allow "normal" usage of 8 cpus and 16GB RAM, and the rest to be dedicated as a "mom" resource for the cluster. Normal cgroups/cpuset configuration also restricts the running jobs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you configure Torque with --enable-cpuset the mom will automatically create a cpuset for each job. Torque isn't really equipped to use part of a machine, but a hack that might work to make this work in conjunction with only using half the machine is to specify np= in the nodes file, and then the mom will restrict the jobs to the first X cpus.